# $\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2 -x}}dx , \int \cosh^2(x)dx ,\int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 2}dx$

Tags: integration

> \begin{align}
> (1) & \int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2 -x}}dx\\
> (2) & \int \cosh^2(x)dx\\
> (3) & \int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 2}dx\\
> \end{align}

$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2 -x}}dx ,  \int \cosh^2(x)dx ,\int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 2}dx$

For the first one, I tried to use trigonometrical substitution, but only accidentally got an answer for $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4 -x^2}}dx\ $ :(

What I was doing:

$\displaystyle x = 2sin(y) $

$\displaystyle dx/dy = 2cos(y) 
= 2sqrt(1 - sin^2(y))
= 2sqrt(1 - (x / 2)^2)
= 2sqrt(1 - x^2 / 4)
= sqrt(4 - x^2)
dx / sqrt(4 - x^2) = dy $

I'd be very grateful for any help and hints!

Comment: Hint:  In choosing a substitution for the first one:  you have a simple **linear** expression (x) raised to a simple power (3), and a complicated **linear** expression (2-x) raised to a complicated power (1/2), and in the denominator! This makes the sub used by Andre Nicolas an excellent first step.  The differentials can be switched with only a sign change,  and the simple power can be applied to the binomial by multiplying out.

Comment: please separate questions per post, it helps with finding answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, use $u=2-x$. Then $dx=-du$, and $x=2-u$.

So $x^3=8-12u+6u^2-u^3$. We want
$$\int (-1)\frac{8-12u+6u^2-u^3}{\sqrt{u}}\,du.$$
Divide term by term. We want
$$\int(-8u^{-1/2}+12u^{1/2}-6u^{3/2}+u^{5/2})\,du.$$

For the second, perhaps use integration by parts. Let $u=\cosh x$ and $dv=\cosh x\,dx$. Then we have $du=\sinh x\,dx$ and we can take $v=\sinh x$. If we think of our integral as $I$, we get
$$I=\sinh x\cosh x-\int\sinh^2 x\,dx.$$
But $\sinh^2 x=\cosh^2 x-1$. Thus
$$I=\sinh x\cosh -\int (\cosh^2 x-1)\,dx=\sinh^2 x-I+\int 1\,dx.$$
Now you should be able to finish.

There are **many** other approaches to the $\cosh^2 x$ problem. for example, there is an analogue of the familiar "double-angle" identity for $\cos 2x$. Or else we can simply express the hyperbolic cosine in terms of exponentials. I wanted to mention the integration by parts approach because it is an important trick for finding **Reduction formulas**.

For the third, first divide the polynomial $x^2+1$ by $x^2+2x+2$. You should get something like $1-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2x+2}$.

for the remaining integral, complete the square to get $(x+1)^2+1$, and let $u=x+1$. Not over yet, but fairly close.

Comment: I think you should be having $\cosh(x)\sinh(x)$ in your integration by parts. Also you can use directly $u=\sqrt{2-x}$  to take care of the root in the first one but that is just preference.

Comment: It is my preference too, in the form $u^2=2-x$. However, I have noticed we are in a minority, so I used the uglier version in the hope it would be more familiar. And thanks for correction on the $\sinh^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

For the last ones:

$$\cosh^2x=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2\right)=\dots$$

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2x+2}=1-\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^2+1(=x^2+2x+2)}=1-\frac{2(x+1)}{x^2+2x+2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$$

So you have, integrating, a polynomial, a logarithm and an inverse trigonometric function...